# How to get Firebase RemoteConfig Parameters in unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-remote-config

I want to get [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcWzj.png) this parameter. I'm trying to do this with this code FirebaseRemoteConfig.GetInstance(Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance).GetValue("VERSION").ToString() but it's returns nothing. Also i've tryed get it with FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultInstance.GetValue but i have same result.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using Firebase.RemoteConfig;

public class GameOpening : MonoBehaviour
{
    Firebase.DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = Firebase.DependencyStatus.UnavailableOther;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                
                Debug.Log(FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultInstance.GetValue("VERSION"));

            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError(
                    "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
            }
        });
    }

    
}
```

Comment: now it's working only on pc, when i run it on android nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You have to Fetch and Activate FirebaseRemoteConfig before you can start using it. Also you should decide on a type of value you will use, Long for example. The next example should work:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using Firebase.RemoteConfig;

public class GameOpening : MonoBehaviour
{
    Firebase.DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = Firebase.DependencyStatus.UnavailableOther;
    // Use this for initialization
    async void Start()
    {
        await Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(async task => {
            var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                await FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultInstance.FetchAsync(TimeSpan.Zero);
                await FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultInstance.ActivateAsync();
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log(FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultInstance.GetValue("VERSION").LongValue);
            }
            else
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(
                    "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
            }
        });    
}
```